# Is there anyway to make Puppeteer perform page actions (like expanding Wikipedia entries) before I make it take a screenshot of a page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping, puppeteer

I tried Googling the answer to this, but only beginner tutorials seem to come up, and the advanced ones only talk about things like taking screenshots and a few other things.

I just want to have Puppeteer expand Wikipedia entries by clicking on them, before taking the screenshot I have it successfully programmed to take now.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example where do you need to "expand an entry" on a Wikipedia page? I am aware of collapsed content only in mobile view. But of course it is possible to do page actions on them to open them: that is the primary functionality of puppeteer.

Comment: I'm scraping the mobile page.  That's why I'm asking.  Don't want the desktop version.

Comment: Noted. Then see my solution below. I've found a bug in the chrome api during writing the answer. Gonna report it to puppeteer team on Github.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

By default the answer to the question would be: you can collect all collapsible heading elements to an array with a simple [`page.$$`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pageselector-1) (alias for `document.querySelectorAll` in the chrome api), then `elementHandle.click` on all of them in a `for...of` loop *(array.map or forEach are not that suitable to do async clicks!)* and finally create a screenshot with `fullPage: true` option.

---

### Additional info about puppeteer bug and its workaround ⚠️

During testing I've found a puppeteer/chromium bug in the last step: `fullPage: true`, so it requires another approach to take the full screenshot of the page.

> When [fullPage] true, [it] takes a screenshot of the full scrollable page [...] [[source]](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions)

The full scrollable page's height is defined at navigation in puppeteer, not at the time we create the screenshot, so if we open more collapsed content after the first render: everything that would appear below the line of the original `document.body.scrollHeight` will be cut.

As a workaround we can recalculate `scrollHeight` (and `scrollWidth`) after all content is opened. I experienced some strange cropping if I didn't wait 1-2 seconds after the clicks, so I forced a `page.waitFor(1500)` before the recalculation. A `page.setViewport` should be applied on the device before the screenshot (`page.screenshot` should not have additional options like `fullPage` or `clip` together with the previous viewport setting!)

### Example

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 6']

async function fn() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.emulate(iPhone)
  await page.goto('https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_the_Year')
  await page.waitForSelector('.collapsible-heading')

  // collect all collapsed headings to an array and click all of them
  const headingHandles = await page.$$('.collapsible-heading')
  for (const el of headingHandles) {
    await el.click()
  }

  // let a bit time for scrollHeight to be finalized
  await page.waitFor(1500)

  // set viewPort to fullPage manually
  const scrollHeight = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.scrollHeight)
  const scrollWidth = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.scrollWidth)
  await page.setViewport({ width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight })

  await page.screenshot({ path: 'wiki.png' })
  await browser.close()
}
fn()
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Actually learned one or two other things from this example too.

Comment: Cool! I am glad it helped.